# Assigning ip addresses to docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, containers, ip-address

I have an infrasucture as the 1st pic. my containers go to endpoints from instance’s ip addresses. I want them to go with their own ip addresses as 2nd pic. There are virtual eth for all ip addresses one by one. I run them with their own ip addresses but they still go with instance’s ip addresses. what should I do? Do I have to use a docker network? what kind of network should I use for that? what the subnet and gateways should be? How can I overcome it?
[image: pic_1_old_architecture]

[image: pic_2_wanted_architecture]

I tried to create a ipvlan docker network but it did not work. I tried to simulate in on AWS but couldn't succeeded it. I can ping each container with their own ip addresses. But I can not ping to customer-endpoint by containers own ip addresses. I see Instance's ip address when I ping to customer-endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal of having your containers communicate with endpoints using their own IP addresses, you could consider using a Docker network with the `macvlan` driver.

It allows you to assign a unique MAC address and IP address to each container, which will allow them to communicate directly with the endpoints using their own IP addresses.

But you need to consider something, which i'm not sure about, it's that maybe you cannot use macvlan on AWS. The physical network needs to support multiple Mac addresses on the wire, and cloud providers with virtualised networking maybe do not support this ( to check ) or maybe it's supported but it needs more configurations on AWS security groups.

For a full control, you may need to be running on a network infrastructure you control, or a provider that supports it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So how can I simulate this situation? Where can I create 25 network drivers and create macvlan docker networks and connect them to each other? I  searched Cisco Packet Tracer but it wasn't possible. Do you have any advice for simulation?

Comment: You can simply use virtualization software like VirtualBox, VMWare, or QEMU. 
You can create multiple virtual machines and install the required operating system and software on them.

Once you have the virtual machines set up, you can create the network drivers and macvlan docker networks within them. You can use Docker to create and manage the macvlan networks.